# How can I disable or change the language of Twitter Moments?

Tags: twitter

Is there any way to tell twitter to disable Twitter Moments, or change it to a non-English language?

I've tried, under https://twitter.com/settings/account , to change my country to Japan, but I'm still getting Twitter Moments for Australia.

Going on holiday in Japan and getting a local SIM card has changed my moments to those of Japan, but that's hardly a feasible solution.